# The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message.. sending from android

Tags: wcf

I am new for wcf services.

some time no error,but some time getting error. please help me on this

The service model

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="ExStreamWCFBinding"
                     closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"                
                    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
              <readerQuotas
                            maxDepth="2147483647"
                            maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                            maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                            maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
                             />
            </binding>
          </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="wsServiceBehavior">
              <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
          <service name="Wcf_tblt_rTest.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" >
            <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://localhost:900/mex/"/>
                <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9000/" />
              </baseAddresses>
            </host>
            <endpoint bindingConfiguration="ExStreamWCFBinding" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Wcf_tblt_rTest.IService1" />
            <endpoint  address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
          </service>
        </services>

      </system.serviceModel>
```

error coming like this

> an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:tm.
>   The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the
>   object of type JSONSample.GetResp. The maximum string content length
>   quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may
>   be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the
>   XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.'.
>   Please see InnerException for more details.'. See server logs for more
>   details. The exception stack trace is:
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, PartInfo part) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameter(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, PartInfo part) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameters(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, PartInfo[] parts, Object[] parameters, PartInfo returnInfo,
>   Object& returnValue) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyCore(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription
>   messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.CompositeDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

Comment: Does this help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731325.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF has many quotas (aka limits) that prevents either malicious or unintentional denial of service attacks.

The message "*The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded*" means that you're sending a string containing more than 8192 characters. You have to alter the config file to allow larger content.

Your settings are not applied here because you specified reader quotas for **wsHttpBinding** and your service is exposed via **basicHttpBinding** : there is mismatch and new quotas settings are not applied.